# "pfctl -s state" output explanation

Tags: freebsd, openbsd

Can anybody tell me where can I find full explanation of "pfctl -s state" output?

`all tcp 192.168.0.123:22 <- 192.168.0.234:38095       ESTABLISHED:ESTABLISHED`

What direction means, which TCP infos are available like "ESTABLISHED:ESTABLISED" and so on.

Good day to you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule means; there is a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (as opposed to [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)) connection from remote IP addres 192.168.0.234 [port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_and_UDP_port) 38095 to local IP address 192.168.0.123 port 22. ESTABLISHED refers to the [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) of the connection.